# Utility of commas in given sentence

Tags: commas

Most of my friends who work in content writing, as a part-time job, earn a lot.

Most of my friends who work in content writing as a part-time job earn a lot.

Are the commas in the given sentence necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you think that "as a part time job" is necessary to specify the kind of work that they do (which makes it a [defining relative clause](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/relative-clauses-defining-relative-clauses)), or whether you think that it simply supplies additional information about the way that they work (a non-defining relative clause). If the latter, commas are required.